# Is there any impact if we enable the root user on an Azure Linux VM?

Tags: linux-on-azure

I create a new Linux VM (CentOS7)on Azure. The root user is disabled by default. So I enable the root user and change the password. I wonder if this will cause any impact on the VM?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks,

Steven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand the capabilities of the **root user** and **sudo user**. **Root** user has a user id of 0 and **unlimited** privileges. You can access any file, execute any system call, run any program if you're a root user. This is the reason a root user is call as superuser. Normally **su** command represents a superuser.

The **sudo** command(short for **superuser do**), allows a normal user **partial** administrative powers. The **sudo** command let you execute commands with superuser privileges as long as your user id is in the **sudoers** file, giving you the necessary authorization. The location of sudoers file is:

**/etc/sudoers**

So **sudo vi /etc/xyz** will allow you to only modify the **xyz** file as you're using the file as a superuser.The sudoers file tells **who** can use the sudo command and **what** one can do with it.

So the **root** user is disabled on Azure by default because they do not want a new user modifies some important files accidentally. But if you're confident enough to handle your own problems then there's nothing to worry about. 
This article explains about root privileges on Linux Virtual Machine in Azure. Here is the link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-use-root-privileges/

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly, but it's bad practice and a [security concern](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root).

Instead you should create a new user and use sudo/su.